# CGAffineTransform to rotate UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, cgaffinetransform

I have a UIButton. On this button I apply a `CGAffineTransform` like this:

```
_mainButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((degrees-heading.trueHeading) * M_PI / 180);
```

In this way I can rotate all my buttons, but I would like to rotate only the background image.

So, `myButton.imageView` should remain at its fixed location. How can make this?

Comment: So, you have to rotate only the background image and *not* the button? `imageToBeRotated.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);`

Answer (score 2):

You have to rotate the `imageView` property of the `UIButton` like this:

```
_mainButton.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((degrees-heading.trueHeading) * M_PI / 180);
```

imageView
The button’s image view. (read-only)

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UIImageView *imageView
```

**Discussion**

Although this property is read-only, its own properties are read/write. Use these properties to configure the appearance and behavior of the button’s view. For example:

```
UIButton *button                   = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeSystem];
button.imageView.exclusiveTouch    = YES;
```

The imageView property returns a value even if the button has not been displayed yet. The value of the property is nil for system buttons.

It's directly from Apple's documentation

Comment: This didn't work for me. Setting the transform of the imageView property simply doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, works well:

```
- (IBAction)toggle:(UIButton *)sender {
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    if (CGAffineTransformEqualToTransform(sender.transform, CGAffineTransformIdentity)) {
        sender.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.999);
    } else {
        sender.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    }
}];
```

}